# OpenAPI Generator issue with Destination service API specification

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I want to get all destinations on subaccount and instance level. In SAP API business Hub, I found the API information and "SAP Cloud SDK" tab to generate code by OpenAPI generator.

https://api.sap.com/api/SAP_CP_CF_Connectivity_Destination/overview

I downloaded the API specification and added dependencies into Cloud SDK for Java project. The code is generated successfully with some errors (unknown models）in generated api classes.

For example in DestinationsOnSubaccountLevelApi.class, model OneOfDestinationNameOnly is imported and used in method but it is not generated in model package.

[image]
[image]

I looked into API specification and found that there were two types of response entity. That is the reason why the code could not be generated properly. I can modify the API specification to make it work but it should not be the long term solution. Is there any other way to fix this issue?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the [SAP Cloud SDK Generator for Open API](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/rest/generate-rest-client) services is not yet able to understand `oneOf` relationship that is modeled in the specification.

As an alternative, would you consider using the [DestinationAccessor](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/connectivity/sdk-connectivity-destination-service#accessing-destinations) API for resolving single destinations?

You can also directly instantiate an `ScpCfDestinationLoader`, which allows for querying all destinations:

```java
ScpCfDestinationLoader loader = new ScpCfDestinationLoader();
DestinationOptions options = DestinationOptions
        .builder()
        .augmentBuilder(ScpCfDestinationOptionsAugmenter.augmenter().retrievalStrategy(ScpCfDestinationRetrievalStrategy.ALWAYS_SUBSCRIBER))
        .build();
Try<Iterable<ScpCfDestination>> destinations = loader.tryGetAllDestinations(options);
```

Similar to the default behavior of DestinationAccessor API, in the code above only the subscriber account will be considered. Other options are:

```
ScpCfDestinationRetrievalStrategy.ALWAYS_SUBSCRIBER
ScpCfDestinationRetrievalStrategy.ALWAYS_PROVIDER
ScpCfDestinationRetrievalStrategy.SUBSCRIBER_THEN_PROVIDER
```

Comment: Is there any plan to support "oneof" relationship in OpenAPI generator?

Comment: The Cloud SDK Generator is relying on the [Open API generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator). Unfortunately it does not support this feature yet. "oneOf" is on their short-term [roadpmap](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/roadmap/#short-term): _"OAS3.0 features support: anyOf, oneOf, callbacks, etc."_ But I honestly wouldn't wait for this. I'm looking forward to this feature for a very long time now.

Comment: Hi, Jerry, this feature should be supported when the Open API generator releases support for it. It's not on the top of their list, but we don't know of any specific timeline for that.

Comment: Please give the latest stable version v6.0.0 (as of this writing) a try as it should provide better support of oneOf for some of the generators: https://twitter.com/oas_generator/status/1529669733934841856